# to be run amuck -- is this a legitimate phrasing?

Tags: grammaticality

Source: [CompTIA A+ Certification All-in-One Exam Guide, 9th Edition (Exam 220-901 & 220-902) by Mike Meyers (2016)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/125958951X)

Example:

> As CPU data bus sizes increased, so too did the need for RAM wide enough to fill the bus. The Intel 80386 CPU, for example, had a 32-bit data bus and thus the need for 32-bit-wide DRAM. Imagine having to line up 32 one-bit-wide DRAM chips on a motherboard. Talk about a waste of space! Figure 5-6 shows motherboard RAM **run amuck**.

As far as I know, the expression [run amuck](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/run+amuck) is only used in an active type of sense in that something or someone can run amuck, but it cannot be run amuck by someone else. Is my thinking valid?

Comment: "This photo shows me eating cake"... Why would this not be legitimate? You need to explain your question more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**run amuck** [sic] is a past-participial phrase modifying "motherboard RAM".

"run" there is intransitive

> This picture shows the weeds in the garden run amok.
>
> This picture shows her hair cut short.
>
> This picture shows the house painted blue.
>
> This picture shows the document doodled on.
>
> This picture shows the moose attacked by wolves.
>
> This picture shows the puddle dried up.

Comment: Although the more "correct" spelling is ["run amok"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/run+amok)

Comment: Was typing as you were commenting.